# На каких ОС работает консольная программа на С/С++?

Tags: ос, c, консоль, c++

Здравствуйте!
Написал программу на C++ (могу на С переписать) в среде разработке MS VS 2010.  Использовал стандартные библиотеки типа `<iostream>`. Работал на Windows 7 Ultimate 64-битная версия.

Вопросы:

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, на каких
       операционная системах моя консольная
       программа будет работать?
2. Как проверить работоспособность
       программы в разных ситуациях и ОС?

Благодарю!

Comment: Если вопрос про переносимость **кода** между ОС, то, избегая использования специфических функций для Microsoft вы добьетесь выполнения и на Windows, и на Linux. Чтобы проверить на Linux, придется его установить, собрать программу и запустить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Если компилировали 32-битное приложение, то, думаю,  будет работать до Windows95 включительно. Если 64-битное, то на всех 64-битных виндах. Первые 64-битные оси (на архитектуре AMD64) - Windows XP 64 bit edition и Windows Server 2003 x64, вышедшие в 2005 году.
2. Установить тестируемую ОС, нормально на диск или в виртуальную машину (типа Virtual Box) и проверить работу. А как еще?

**P.S.** Если интересует проблема переносимости **кода** между разными семействами ОС, то при использовании только стандартных библиотек переносимость должна быть гарантирована поддержкой стандарта компилятором вне зависимости от ОС.